# Edit existing entry of developer story

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, accessibility

I have just filled my developer story this evening on Stack Overflow, and everything doesn't appear exactly as I want / as it should. When I go to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/<my_id>) I see how to add something new in my profile. Buttons for: a new position, blog, feature or app, etc. seem obvious. I also may read what I have just filled and what was my last job position.

**But I don't see how to edit this existing entry**.

I want to edit it first of all because dates are wrong: I started in 2016 and ended in 2017, this is correct, but I worked there exactly for one year, not two as the site shows, incorrectly. When I have been asked, I hadn't the choice to select the beginning and ending months, therefore it has automatically computed 2 years, although in fact I started in September 2016 and am going to end in August 2017.

Additionally, I think I found a typo or two...

Please help me, tell me how to proceed. Alternatively, if there is no way to edit directly, at least tell me how to delete it.

Important note: I'm a screen reader user; Stack Overflow is far from being fully accessible; I may help.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. We are working on this (and other) accessibility issue right now on the developer story. In the meantime, I have fixed the dates on your dev story position, but let me know if you'd rather delete the entry.

Answer (score 3):

At least in my developer story, there is a little gear that appears in the upper right corner of each entry. When I hover over it, it gives me the option to "edit" or "delete".

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image: Stackoverflow "top post" card from developer story. Small gear in upper right corner is hovered over to display "edit" and "delete" options.]

Comment: OK. Your picture can't unfortunately help me as I can't see the screen. So it probably means that there is no accessible solution for me. CAn someone from stackoverflow team have the rights to delete the entry for me ? Other secondary question, would it be useful that I post a general screen reader accessibility request here on meta, or would it be completely useless ? Thank you.

Comment: @QuentinC I missed that last line, my apologies. Indeed if this hover option is not "visible" to your screen reader, that represents a pretty major missing feature of the developer story.

Comment: @QuentinC I think that would be very useful. Tag it as a feature request and maybe link to this question.

Answer (score -2):

I just found a trick to edit/update our details in development story.

[Just click here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/join) and then click on button saying `Update your Developer Story`

Now you'll see the hover on every item once again to edit information for them.